# R - Could not find function "dashboardPagePlus"

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I try to create a shiny app using dashboardPagePlus.

I already import shinydashboard and shinydashboardPlus package. But I got an error message when I run UI.

> Error in dashboardPagePlus(skin = "black", dashboardHeaderPlus(title =
> "title"),  :    could not find function "dashboardPagePlus"

I don`t know why. I try to run the example code from RDocumentation. But Still have this problem.

Example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

How to fix it?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you update the package to version 2.0.0? [If you updated from v0.7.5, you will have to rewrite most of the code...](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinydashboardPlus/vignettes/shinydashboardPlus.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The package version is ‘2.0.1’. I will try to rewrite the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in the comments, if you use {shinydashboardPlus} >= 2.0.0, you would need to rewrite your code as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
      skin = "dark",
      controlbarMenu(
        id = "menu"
      )
    ),
    title = "DashboardPage"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know the reason.